# Unexpected text size staircase effect while looping database

Tags: php

I just created the v.2 of my database requesting system. However, for some reason I have this "Staircase effect", it prints out the data but then it prints it over and over and over and over again increasing the size of the font. What is this?! My code:

```
$query=$db->prepare("SELECT post_id, title, body, category FROM posts INNER JOIN categories ON categories.category_id");
    $query->execute();
    $query->bind_result($post_id, $title, $body, $category);    
while($query->fetch()):?>
    <article>
    <h2><?php echo $title?><h2>
    <p><?php echo $body?></p>
    <p2>Category:</p2><?php echo $category?>
    <?php endwhile ?>
    </article>
```

You can see the effect @ http://wrya.x10host.com/highflyer/index.php
Can anyone help me fix this and explain to me what I did wrong?

Comment: +1 for creative interpretation

Comment: Shouldn't you close the article tag within the loop?

Comment: It's always a good idea to run your page through a validator when you have problems like this. http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwrya.x10host.com%2Fhighflyer%2Findex.php&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it help to move the `</article>` one line up, inside your while-loop? Like so:

```
$query=$db->prepare("SELECT post_id, title, body, category FROM posts INNER JOIN categories ON categories.category_id");
$query->execute();
$query->bind_result($post_id, $title, $body, $category);    
while($query->fetch()):?>
    <article>
        <h2><?php echo $title?></h2>
        <p><?php echo $body?></p>
        <p2>Category:</p2><?php echo $category?>
    </article>
<?php endwhile ?>
```

Comment: the h2 closing tag is also borked

Comment: @mensi Good point, missed that. Updated my code snippet with that fix as well!

Answer (score 1):

What exactly is a p2 tag?

Pretty sure that's not a valid HTML tag in any DOCTYPE. The easiest way to see the problem is to view the source in Firefox, it will highlight in red any unclosed tags and I'd hazard a guess that's the problem.

You also have lots of opening article tags inside your loop, but the closing tag is outside.

Comment: p2 tag - Derp moment, confused it with h tag :P Fixed